# GCD for large numbers

Tags: sml, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to create a gcd function that handles very big numbers . Thus , anything that I've tried so far leads to errors . For example :

```
fun gcd(a : Int.toLarge, b : Int.toLarge): Int.toLarge =
  if   b = 0
  then a
  else gcd(b, a mod b)`
```

gives me the following error :

```
Error:unbound type constructor : toLarge in path Int.toLarge
```

Could someone give me some advice , the rest of my program seems to work fine . Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You treat `Int.toLarge` as if it's a type, but it's a function. The type you're looking for is *IntInf.int*. A gcd function would look the same regardless of what type of number you put into it; but you might have to refer to the arithmetic operators from another module.

Here's a gcd function for the type *Int.int*:

```
fun gcd (a, 0) = a
  | gcd (a, b) = gcd (b, a - b*(a div b))
```

And because SML/NJ's arithmetic operators are overloaded, here's one for *IntInf.int*:

```
fun gcd (a, 0) = a : IntInf.int
  | gcd (a, b) = gcd (b, a - b*(a div b))
```